# Remove translation from the title field

Tags: 8, i18n-l10n

Is there a way to **disable** translations from Title field in each content type.

In the /admin/config/regional/content-language, when I remove translations from Title fields it gives `Fatal error:  Maximum execution time of 120 seconds exceeded`. No matter what time I give in the ini file this always happens. Is there a way to correct this? Or is there a way to remove Title fields translation without going to content-language

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, there is another way to do this in configuration. You can change

```
  translatable: true
```

in `core.base_field_override.node.[content-type].title.yml`.

If you don't find this configuration file, then there are no changes made so far for the title field. You can do this for example by modifying "Title field label" in the content type, which is also stored in this configuration and if it doesn't exist it will be created, so that you'll find the yaml in the exported config.

After you've changed the field label, export the configuration, open for each content type the mentioned yaml file, change translatable to false and reimport the configuration again.

See https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/configuration-management/workflow-using-the-drupal-ui or if you have installed drush use these two commands:

```
drush config-export
drush config-import
```

see https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/configuration-management/workflow-using-drush.

Comment: Mhh, I do know what you are talking of, as I'm using configuration export/import on a regular base. I only fear, a beginner might have some trouble understanding your answer.

Comment: OK, but what should we do, if a possible solution needs some medium level skills?

Comment: Telling him where to find configuration export/import or how to create the above mentioned files. ;) - Or just a link for further reading https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/configuration-management/managing-your-sites-configuration

Comment: @MarioSteinitz Don't underestimate Batman. He will find a way.

Comment: @leymannx Yeah. Batman always has a way :p This worked man thanks :)